# Exercise 4.(a) on p.30 in "Analysis on Manifolds" by James R. Munkres. Is my solution ok? Please tell me a simpler or smarter solution.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I am reading "Analysis on Manifolds" by James R. Munkres.
There is the following exercise in this book:

> Exercise 4.(a) on p.30
> Show that if $Q$ is a rectangle, then $Q$ equals the closure of $\mathrm{Int}\, Q$.

The definition of a rectangle in this book is the following:

> $Q = \{(x_1, \dots, x_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n\mid a_i \leq x_i \leq b_i \text{ for all }i\}$.

My solution for Exercise 4.(a) on p.30 is the following:

> $Q = \bigcap_{i=1}^{n}{(\{(x_1, \dots, x_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n\mid a_i \leq x_i\}\cap\{(x_1, \dots, x_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n\mid x_i \leq b_i\})}$.
> In general, $\mathrm{Int}\, (S_1\cap\cdots\cap S_n)=\mathrm{Int}\, S_1\cap\cdots\cap\mathrm{Int}\, S_n$ holds.
> So, $\mathrm{Int}\, Q = \bigcap_{i=1}^{n}{(\{(x_1, \dots, x_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n\mid a_i < x_i\}\cap\{(x_1, \dots, x_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n\mid x_i < b_i\})}$.
> In general, $\overline{S_1\cap\cdots\cap S_n}\subset\overline{S_1}\cap\cdots\cap\overline{S_n}$ holds.
> So, $\overline{\mathrm{Int}\, Q} \subset \bigcap_{i=1}^{n}{(\{(x_1, \dots, x_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n\mid a_i \leq x_i\}\cap\{(x_1, \dots, x_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n\mid x_i \leq b_i\})}=Q$.

> Conversely, let $(x_1, \dots, x_n) \in Q$.
> If $a_i < x_i$ and $x_i < b_i$ for all $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$, then $(x_1,\dots,x_n) \in\mathrm{Int}\, Q\subset\overline{\mathrm{Int}\, Q}$.
> If $a_i \leq x_i$ and $x_i \leq b_i$ for all $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$ and ($a_i = x_i$ or $x_i = b_i$ for some $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$),
> then $a_i < x_i < b_i$ or $a_i = x_i < b_i$ or $a_i < x_i = b_i$ holds for each $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$.
> If $a_i < x_i < b_i$, then $((a_i, b_i)\cap(x_i-\frac{x_i-a_i}{2}, x_i+\frac{b_i-x_i}{2}))\setminus\{x_i\}\neq\emptyset$.
> If $a_i = x_i < b_i$, then $((a_i, b_i)\cap(x_i-\frac{b_i-x_i}{2}, x_i+\frac{b_i-x_i}{2}))\setminus\{x_i\}\neq\emptyset$.
> If $a_i < x_i = b_i$, then $((a_i, b_i)\cap(x_i-\frac{x_i-a_i}{2}, x_i+\frac{x_i-a_i}{2}))\setminus\{x_i\}\neq\emptyset$.
> So, $(x_1,\dots,x_n) \in\overline{\mathrm{Int}\, Q}$.

> So, $Q=\overline{\mathrm{Int}\, Q}$.

***Is my solution ok?***
I think my solution is not smart.
At first glance, I wondered this exercise was very easy.
But now I think this exercise is not very easy.
I cannot judge if this exercise is very easy or not.
***Is this exercise very easy or not?***
***Please tell me a simpler or smarter solution for this exercise?***

Comment: Not having the book (and thus not knowing what statements prior to this exercise can already be used) - I would probably break it up into two simpler statements: (a) The interior of a closed rectangle  $[a_1,b_1]\times\cdots\times[a_n,b_n]$ is the "corresponding" open rectangle $(a_1,b_1)\times\cdots\times(a_n,b_n)$; (b) The closure of an open rectangle $(a_1,b_1)\times\cdots\times(a_n,b_n)$ is the "corresponding" closed rectangle $[a_1,b_1]\times\cdots\times[a_n,b_n]$. (Everywhere assuming $a_i<b_i$.)

Comment: @StinkingBishop Thank you very much for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Stinking Bishop, thank you very much for your comment.

Let $x := (x_1, \dots, x_n)$.
If there exists $i \in \{1,\dots,n\}$ such that $x_i\leq a_i$ or $b_i\leq x_i$, then it is obvious that $x$ is not an interior point of $Q$.
Conversely, if $a_i < x_i < b_i$ for all $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$, then it is obvious that $x$ is an interior point of $Q$.
So, $\mathrm{Int}\, Q = (a_1,b_1)\times\dots\times(a_n,b_n)$.

If there exists $i \in \{1,\dots,n\}$ such that $x_i< a_i$ or $b_i< x_i$, then it is obvious that $x$ is not a limit point of $\mathrm{Int}\, Q$.
Conversely, if $a_i \leq x_i \leq b_i$ for all $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$, then it is obvious that $x$ is a limit point of $\mathrm{Int}\, Q$.
So, $Q=\overline{\mathrm{Int}\, Q}$.